# Truncate a floating point number in prolog

Tags: prolog, yap

How to truncate a floating point number up to N decimal places in Prolog?

Is there any built-in tool for this?

Comment: Just got that. using format/2 will do it.

Comment: Consider answering and closing your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is easy to define a predicate `truncate/3` in Prolog. Let's say that we want truncate a real number `X` up to `N` decimal places and store its result in `Result`. Using the mathematical function for truncation in [this Wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation), we can define the predicate as follows:

```
    % truncation for positive numbers
    truncate(X,N,Result):- X >= 0, Result is floor(10^N*X)/10^N, !.

    % truncation for negative numbers
    truncate(X,N,Result):- X <0, Result is ceil(10^N*X)/10^N, !.
```

I use cut because the two above cases are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I was wondering why there is no inbuilt predicate for such simple thing. Although format/2 predicate works but I later realised that using format/2, we cannot save the output in any variable, the output will go straight to the stream.

Comment: Because initially Prolog was not intended for numerical computation. It may seem simple in procedural language, but in Prolog we have to adapt with declarative (in particular logic) programming paradigm.

Comment: You should always cut as soon as possible, here immediately after the `X>=0` test. The cut in the last clause is unnecessary.You can also simplify your code by using the built-in `truncate` function instead of `floor` and `ceil`.